# Angular - Accessing ngrx store in a 'then' block

Tags: angular, firebase, angular6, observable, ngrx

I am using Angular6 and Cloud Firestore (not realtime database). I have a service which holds a function which adds a document to a collection and then using a `.then` block to get the ID of the document that was just created and then do some other logic. In this function, I want to access some shopping cart contents which I am keeping in a `Store`, using `ngrx`. In my ngOnInit I have the following code which subscribes and gets the contents and assigns it to a `cartContents` (global variable in the service).

```
this.myState = this.store.select('shoppingCart');
this.shoppingCartStateSubscription = this.myState.subscribe(val => {
   this.cartContents = val.basketList;
});
```

I then want to the able to access the value of `this.cartContents` inside the `.then` block, however, the value comes up as undefined. What am I doing wrong/misunderstanding?

Code for the function:

```
processPayment(token: any, amount: number){
        const payment = { token, amount };

this.paymentCollection.doc(`${this.userId}`).collection('payments').add({
            payment
        })
        .then(docRef => {
            console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
            this.docRefId = docRef.id;
            this.db.collection("payments/"+`${this.userId}`+"/payments").doc(`${this.docRefId}`)
        .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
            console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
            if(doc.data().status === "succeeded"){

                const updatedBalance = this.balance - amount;;

                let writeBatch = firebase.firestore().batch();

                //Update purchased lessons ref
                console.log(this.cartContents); //APEARS AS UNDEFINED

                for(let buyable of this.cartContents){
                    let purchasedLessonsRef = this.afs.firestore.doc(`/purchased_lessons/${this.userId}/lessons/${buyable.b_id}`);
                    writeBatch.update(purchasedLessonsRef, buyable);
                }

                //Update balance ref
                let userBalanceRef = this.afs.firestore.doc(`/users/${this.userId}`);
                writeBatch.update(userBalanceRef, {balance: updatedBalance});

                this.docRefId = null;

                return writeBatch.commit().then(function () {
                    console.log("commiting batch")
                });
            }
        });

        console.log("finished function");
        })
    .catch(error => console.error("Error adding document: ", error))
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the values in onNgInit()?

Comment: Yes correct, subscribing and assigning the value of the cart to the variable cartContents in the ngOnInit()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting the value on `OnNgInit()`, only reason I can think of is the binding of `this`.

Suspect is `function(doc){//stuff}`, change that to `(doc) => {//stuff}`

You can also try replacing all your functions with `arrow` function.

```
    processPayment = (token: any, amount: number) =>{
        const payment = { token, amount };

this.paymentCollection.doc(`${this.userId}`).collection('payments').add({
            payment
        })
        .then(docRef => {
            console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
            this.docRefId = docRef.id;
            this.db.collection("payments/"+`${this.userId}`+"/payments").doc(`${this.docRefId}`)
        .onSnapshot((doc) => {
            console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
            if(doc.data().status === "succeeded"){

                const updatedBalance = this.balance - amount;;

                let writeBatch = firebase.firestore().batch();

                //Update purchased lessons ref
                console.log(this.cartContents); //APEARS AS UNDEFINED

                for(let buyable of this.cartContents){
                    let purchasedLessonsRef = this.afs.firestore.doc(`/purchased_lessons/${this.userId}/lessons/${buyable.b_id}`);
                    writeBatch.update(purchasedLessonsRef, buyable);
                }

                //Update balance ref
                let userBalanceRef = this.afs.firestore.doc(`/users/${this.userId}`);
                writeBatch.update(userBalanceRef, {balance: updatedBalance});

                this.docRefId = null;

                return writeBatch.commit().then(() => {
                    console.log("commiting batch")
                });
            }
        });

        console.log("finished function");
        })
    .catch(error => console.error("Error adding document: ", error))
}
    }
```

Other alternative is to bind this explicitely like:

```
.snapshot(function(doc){
//function body
}).bind(this) // this is binding the correct context (this) to the function
```

Comment: Sorry, but, where am I using `function(doc){//stuff}`. All of my code uses arrow functions. Could you please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: .onSnapshot(function(doc) {

Comment: Hey, sorry, I saw it, changed and unfortunately didn't make a difference

Comment: Any more suggestions?

Comment: @JonnySprouse did you change all functions to arrow? including processPayment? or did you try copy pasting the code in the answer?

Comment: Hi, I copied your code, and tried the alternative `bind(this)` method, however, I still get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: When I get the value of the cart contents anywhere else, out of the `.then()`, it gets it fine.

Comment: Sorry, I just double checked and this did work! Thanks!!